# Multirow hover in repeater table

Tags: html, css, html-table, repeater

I have an *asp repeater* in which I display multiple datarows. It would be great if I could have a hover effect on 3 tablerows (not 3 datarows) at the same time.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepTime" runat="server">                     
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="repTable">
            <tr class="Headertemplate">            
                <th></th>                                   
                <th>Titel</th>                                
            </tr>                           
    </HeaderTemplate>        
    <ItemTemplate>     
            <tr class="Itemtemplate">     
                <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDesnote" Text='<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i>' ForeColor="Black" OnClick="btnDesnote_Click"/></td>                                
                <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>'/></td>                               
            </tr>
            <tr id="Desnote0" style="display:none;" runat="server" >
                <th colspan="6">Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Desnote1" style="display:none;" runat="server" >
                <td colspan="6">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDescription" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" Enabled="false" Width="100%"/>
                </td>                               
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>  
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>                       
            <tr class="Altertemplate">                                                             
                <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDesnote" Text='<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i>' ForeColor="Black" OnClick="btnDesnote_Click"/></td>                                
                <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>'/></td>                               
            </tr>
            <tr id="Desnote0" style="display:none;" runat="server" >
                <th colspan="6">Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Desnote1" style="display:none;" runat="server" >
                <td colspan="6">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDescription" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" Enabled="false" Width="100%"/>
                </td>                               
            </tr> 
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>                     
    <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>                                  
</asp:Repeater>
```

the result looks like this:
*sorry for my drawing skills

[image]

the red part is one datarow and is made of 3table rows. With the arrow you can show tablerow 2 and 3 which are the description header and textbox.

Now should on hover over the *itemtemplate* only these rows light up in gray, red I don't care which color.

Comment: You could probably achieve this using CSS sibling selectors, so something along the lines of .Altertemplate + tr to select the second row and .Altertemplate + tr + tr to select the third (and obviously targetting anything inside using further selectors) combined with the :hover pseudo class.

Comment: i tried that but when you hover over row 2 than row 3 and 4 will get the effect and not row 1 and 3.

Comment: Yes, tricky! Ideally you'd have some parent element to put the hover on, but in this case you don't and probably shouldn't put anything between the tr tags. What about (dare I say it), nested tables? Dirty, but it would give you a structure to use to target three rows at once.

Comment: Just tried doing something different ... might be a solution? See the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrmWoo

Comment: Even better (just found this out), you can use tbody tags around each set of three rows. The spec says you can have one or more tbody tags. Then just put a class on those, and use the :hover on that for the background colour. Probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: thats exacly what i was looking for thx. works perfectly with tbody tag

Comment: if you post it as answer i can mark it properly

Comment: Added as an answer now ... glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add <tbody> tags around each set of three rows and then add styling to the tbody tags to apply the background color using the :hover psuedo class.